# MakeFile how to refer to one of the library's script sh file

Tags: go, makefile

I have a main repository that has the `run_test.sh` file, all my other repositories will always download this main repository as a vendor package.

I have another 4 repositories need the `run_test.sh` in the Makefile too. For now, I just duplicate this run_test.sh file in all the repo, so in each repo, inside my Makefile, I just simply put:

```
sample:
   @sh ./scripts/run_test.sh $(BIN_DIR)
```

But this is slightly annoying if I have to duplicate whenever I created a new repo and update all if there's any changes. Is there a way to refer the script file from the main repo library?

Not familiar with shell commands, have tried to use -L or created $(LIB_DIR), but all not working...

Comment: Can you run it from the shell directly, like `./scripts/run_tests.sh "$BIN_DIR"`?

Comment: Hi @Andreas thanks for commenting, if I run locally from the shell, I see: zsh: permission denied